# extracting first line from multiple text files in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I would like to extract single lines from a text file and put them into a new table based on the change of "id".

For example I want lines 1,53 and 87 to be apart of my new table
It would be very time consuming to do it manually as I have so many files.

*Is there a way to do this using R?*

```
"row.name" "date"   "latitude"  "longitude" "depth" "id"
"1" "2014-12-10 17:37:23"   -38.6219483442355   142.930328034342    0   "0005"
"2" "2014-12-10 17:37:27"   -38.6219774268193   142.930269244481    0   "0005"
...
"53" "2014-12-10 17:37:31"  -38.6220065094031   142.93021045462     0   "0009"
"54" "2014-12-10 17:37:35"  -38.6220355919869   142.930151664759    0   "0009"
"55" "2014-12-10 17:37:39"  -38.6220646745707   142.930092874898    0.61"0009"
...
"87" "2014-12-10 17:37:47"  -38.6221228397384   142.929975295176    0   "0018"
"89" "2014-12-10 17:37:51"  -38.6221519223222   142.929916505315    0   "0018"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data frame, you can use `dplyr` to group by id, and then as the `summarise` function, call `head` and have it select only the first row (instead of the default 6).  Here is a toy example.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("0005", "0005", "0009", "0009", "0009"), content = c(1:5))
df$id <- as.factor(df$id)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(single = head(content, 1))
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

    id single
1 0005      1
2 0009      3
```